# Finite morphisms between affine schemes are projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I'm trying to solve the following exercise of Liu's book (about algebraic geometry).

Let $f : Spec(B) \mapsto  Spec(A)$ be a ﬁnite morphism. We want to show that f
is projective.

(a)  Let us ﬁrst suppose that $B = A[T ]/(P(T))$, where $P = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}a_{i}T^{i}$
with $a_{n} = 1$.
Let $\tilde{P} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}T^{i}s^{n-i}$. Show that the natural morphism $Spec(B) \mapsto Proj A[T, S]/(\tilde{P} (T, S))$ is an
isomorphism.

(b) Conclude in the general case.

---

For (a), **I don't know if it's an isomorphism**. But if it is, then $f$ can be factored has the isomorphism followed by the closed immersion $Proj A[T, S]/(\tilde{P} (T, S)) \mapsto \mathbb{P}^{1}_{A}$ followed by the natural projection on $Spec(A)$  so it is projective.

For (b), let $b_{1}, ..., b_{n}$ be a set of generators of $B$ on $A$. Each $b_{i}$ is a $0$ of a monic polynomial $P_{i}$ that we can suppose of minimal degree $n_{i}$ (to verify this property). So, $f : Spec(B) \mapsto Spec(A)$ is the composite $Spec(B) = Spec(A[b_{0}, ..., b_{n}]) \mapsto Spec(A[b_{n-1}, ..., b_{0}]) \mapsto ... \mapsto Spec(A)$ and each morphism  $Spec(A_{i}) = Spec(A[b_{i}, ..., b_{0}]) \mapsto Spec(A[b_{i-1}, ..., b_{0}]) = Spec(A_{i-1})$  is projective by (a) since those it has the same nature as the natural finite morphism $Spec(A_{i-1}[T]/(P_{i}(T)) Spec(A_{i})$ (since a finite map between algebra is integral and by euclidean division by a unitary polynomial which holds on arbitrary rings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can endow $B$ with the trivial graded structure, $B_0 = A, B_i = B \ \forall \ i > 0$. Then show that you have a graded ring morphism $\varphi \colon A[T,S]/(\widetilde{P}(T,S)) \longrightarrow A[T]/(P(T))$ given by $T \longmapsto T, S \longmapsto 1$. If the LHS is inherited the natural graded structure of $A[T,S]$ ($\widetilde{P}(T,S)$ is homogeneous), then $\varphi$ is a morphism of graded rings. By **lemma 3.40** in Qing Liu, you have a morphism $\operatorname{Proj}(B) \setminus V_+(\varphi(C_+)B) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Proj}(A[T,S]/(\widetilde{P}(T,S))$ but $\varphi(C_+) = B_+$ so this is really a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(B) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Proj}(A[T,S]/(\widetilde{P}(T,S))$ and by the local description in **lemma 3.40**, you can show that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: It works and it's elegant. Just what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: KReiser, I saw your comment. It was just about the isomorphism. The rest was clear for me.